# STI and RSpec problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, single-table-inheritance

Assume that I have these models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Bob < Person
  def name
    'Bob'
  end
end

class John < Person
  def name
    'John'
  end
end
```

This code works well:

```
# in controller:
@persons = Person.all

# in view:
- @persons.each do |person|
  %p= person.name
```

But in my spec file I get error when I write something like this:

```
it "display person names" do
  Bob.create!
  @person = Person.all.first
  print @person.name # Error: undefined method 'name' for #<Person:0x...>
end
```

But this code works fine:

```
it "display person names" do
  Bob.create!
  @person = Bob.all.first
  print @person.name
end
```

What do I do wrong?

P.S. The problem is only in RSpec files. The same code in controllers works well.

UPDATE: the solution is found! I should run "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test" (last migration "add_type_to_person" was applied only to development database")

Comment: copy-paste here the output "@person = Person.all.first; print @person.inspect"

Comment: I can't copy-paste, because it is an abstract example. But in my real project "@person = Person.all.first; print @person.inspect" in RSpect file tells that the object @person doesn't have a "type" column, although in controller it has column "type" with value "Bob".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make sure the schema of your test database matches the schema in your development database using this before running your tests:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

If you invoke rspec using `rake spec`, the prepare will happen for you.

Answer (score 0):

What we don't know is what your schema or data look like.  (John and Bob are tables?)

I would have to guess, though, that Person does not have a name attribute, and that is why the first test fails.

Since I don't know what you are trying to do here, I can't advise any further -- but the simplest solution is to put the name method on the Person object.  (Assuming that it's a virtual column of some sort, maybe you could abstract it out from the data so that you don't have to define it in the subclasses.)

Comment: I use single-table inheritance (STI). There is a table "persons" and two subclasses - "Bob" and "John". Adding method "name" to "Person" class doesn't help because I want to call a child method when I write "@person.name" (for Bob it should return "Bob").

Comment: Well, it will make the test work.  You either need to add a name method to Person, or change the test.  If you are never going to use Person.name, then don't test for it...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in your fixtures. I guess one of your fixtures does not have proper value in `type` column, and by accident, this one record happens to be returned by `Person.all.first`

`Bob.all` is not the same as `Person.all` - the first will return you only the records for which `type = "Bob"`, the second will return all records.

Usually using `.first` in tests is not a good idea. Usually you do not know (do not specify) the sorting order, so the returned record is random.

In this case, check the value of the `type` field of the record returned by the failing test. I guess there will be some clue.